# Installing Issues

Tags: php, config, sugarcrm, phplist

All,

Great! The boss comes in and said has these installed and working on his laptop before Monday:

1. SugarCRM CE,
2. PHPList,
3. SEOPanel,

His is an Acer Aspire 7739Z running Kubuntu 16.04 LTS

So I have them installed but none are working right.  I installed these 5 years ago on our server, but too long ago to remember.

Both SEOPanel and Sugar give blank/near blank screens, so consider those config issues.  Need a list of good "config" howtos for these, not finding what I need on these.  SEOPanel has less docs than Sugar, but Sugar is soo confusing.  Need step by step configs on these with some testing sources, so I can make changes and see the impacts.  I'm not getting any errors but just "near blank" screens on each of these.  All the HOWTOs I'm finding only address specific errors, but not "blank screen" issues.

Sorry I can't give more specific details.

PHPList uses gmail as the SMTP and remember this as very troublesome, when I installed before as SMTP to google/gmail is very problematic.  Unfortunately though I wrote this up before, have no idea where to find my own posts on how I resolved that 5 years back. I remember having to go through over 15 HOWTOs to find the answers needed, with 2 ultimately having the final details I needed to complete the config of SMTP.

All help appreciated.  Already 8pm here and have to work tomorrow, so need help or not going to get these done in time.

Thanks!

OMR

Comment: looks like the software and the php-version never fit together

Comment: Sugar: Did you check the php/apache error logs? Also sugarcrm.log can contain errors, although blank screen sounds like php died before Sugar even loaded. Probably because of version issues (Sugar 6.5 CE was written for PHP 5.4 to 5.6 or something? Doesn't Ubuntu 16.04 come with PHP 7.0 which is pretty incompatible with those versions?)

Comment: Possibly useful if you need an older version of PHP: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php

Answer (score 2):

Just check for 2 things. If this works, it will save your lots of time.

1. Since installation is done on personal laptop, give complete access of the sugarcrm folder i.e. `sudo chmod -R 777 <path to sugarcrm Folder>`
2. Please check if mbstring is enabled in php ini. To check create a file php file eg. `info.php` with code

Let me know if this worked.

Comment: I learned that SugarCRM CE stopped development at PHP6.4/MySQL6.4.  I'm on PHP7/MySQL7 so is a compatibility issue.  I have a server running older code so will have to install there!

Comment: Yes correct. You can use PHP Version 5.6. I have installed in version 5.6.36. There is another crm which is developed over Sugarcrm called Suitecrm, which is themed version of sugarcrm with many other modules. You can try that as well if you don't want to switch your php version. Suitecrm runs on php latest version and fully opensource. I have installed it in version 7.2.7.  For your reference. [link](https://crm.scideas.in)